# Recurring payment integration with Realex/Global payment

Tags: payment-gateway, realex-payments-api, global-payments-api

I am trying to create a recurring payment for Global payment gateway. But getting below error -

> The selected gateway does not support this transaction type.

```
$config = new ServicesConfig();
$config->merchantId = "MerchantId";
$config->accountId = "AccountId";
$config->sharedSecret = "SharedSecret";
$config->serviceUrl = "https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay";
$config->hostedPaymentConfig = new HostedPaymentConfig();
$config->hostedPaymentConfig->version = HppVersion::VERSION_2;
if ($recurring){
    $config->hostedPaymentConfig->cardStorageEnabled = "1";
}
$service = new HostedService(
    $config
);

$hostedPaymentData = new HostedPaymentData();
$hostedPaymentData->offerToSaveCard = true; // display the save card tick box
$hostedPaymentData->customerExists = false; // new customer
echo $service->Authorize($amount)
    ->withCurrency($currency_code)
    ->withRecurringInfo(RecurringType::FIXED, RecurringSequence::FIRST)
    ->withOrderId($order_id) 
    ->withHostedPaymentData($hostedPaymentData)
    ->serialize();
```

On server side I am getting POST response from payment gateway with customer id and payment id.

```
$parsedResponse = $service->parseResponse(json_encode($_POST));
$responseValues  = $parsedResponse->responseValues; // get values accessible by key
$schedule = createSchedule($responseValues);


function createSchedule($responseValues)
{
    $schedule = new Schedule();

    $customerKey = $responseValues['SAVED_PAYER_REF'];
    $paymentMethodKey = $responseValues['SAVED_PMT_REF'];
    $orderId = $responseValues['ORDER_ID'];
    $amount = $responseValues['AMOUNT'];

    $schedule->id               = getIdentifier('CreditV');
    $schedule->customerKey      = $customerKey;
    $schedule->paymentKey       = $paymentMethodKey;
    $schedule->amount           = $amount;//$_REQUEST['a3'] * 100;
    $schedule->currency         = 'EUR';//$_REQUEST['cc']
    $schedule->startDate        = date('mdY'); //, strtotime("last day of next month")
    $schedule->paymentSchedule  = PaymentSchedule::DYNAMIC; //or PaymentSchedule::FIRST_DAY_OF_THE_MONTH
    $schedule->frequency        = ScheduleFrequency::WEEKLY; //'Monthly', 'Bi-Monthly', 'Quarterly', 'Semi-Annually'
    $schedule->numberOfPayments = 4;
    $schedule->description      = 'Test';
    $schedule->poNumber         = $orderId;
    $schedule->reprocessingCount = 1;
    $schedule->emailReceipt      = 'Never';
    $schedule->status            = 'Active';
    $response = $schedule->create();

    return $response;
}

function getIdentifier($id)
{
    $identifierBase = '%s-%s' . substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 0, 10);
    return sprintf($identifierBase, date('Ymd'), $id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question. Unfortunately, the Global Payments SDK right now does not support the creation of scheduled payments with the Global Payments Ecommerce solution. It does work with the Heartland gateway but that is a separate product that is currently US only.

If you are string cards with the Hosted Payments Page, you can setup schedules against them using our XML API: https://developer.globalpay.com/#!/api/payment-scheduler

Comment: Can you please direct me how can I create that xml? Do I need to write code to create Sha1has?

Comment: And how we have to send that xml? Where is the url?

Comment: Did anyone get the answer as to which URL to send for the XML request?

Comment: The XML API endpoints are outlined here: https://developer.globalpay.com/#!/api/getting-started